# how to select rows in first query but but not present in second query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following MYSQL query for which am trying to select rows which are present in query#1 but not present in query#2 ,I've tried to use NOT EXISTS but that concept is not working for my use case,I provided sample data and results,is there an alternative approach for my usecase?what am I looking for?

```
SELECT
    si.software_image_id,
    si.software_image,
    sib.software_image_build,
    si.software_image_tag_id
FROM software_product_builds spb
INNER JOIN software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
INNER JOIN software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
INNER JOIN software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id 
WHERE spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-7' and  NOT EXISTS

(SELECT
    si.software_image_id,
    si.software_image,
    sib.software_image_build,
    si.software_image_tag_id
FROM software_product_builds spb
INNER JOIN software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
INNER JOIN software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
INNER JOIN software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id
WHERE spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-6')
```

Query#1 result

[image: query1]

Query#2 result

[image: query2]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
1781    BTFM.HW_NPR.1.1 BTFM.HW_NPR.1.1-00007-QCACHROM-1    2
```

Comment: I might be looking at this too quickly, but the expected output does indeed appear in both queries right? so to get your expected output you would want to say it does `EXIST` in both queries?

Comment: @JasonJoslin - No,it only appears in query#1 ,notice the last few digits BTFM.HW_NPR.1.1-`00007`,it is BTFM.HW_NPR.1.1-`00006` in query#2

Comment: The subquery in the not exists is not a correlated one, therefore its results do not change as mysql loops through the results of the outer query. You need to connect the outer query with the subquery using the subquery's where clause. Sonce again you did not describe the problem in detail, it is difficult to suggest a solution. You may have to check all 4 fields.

Comment: @Shadow - I gave the expected output aswell....its okay to stay out of this thread if you dont have information rather than discouraging others

Comment: why do you say so?from my POV I explained everything in detail,if you dont understand and feel something is missing,why dont you ask and explain in detail rather than accusing?you are not the accusation starter,so you keep them to yourself and chose to ignore the details provided....also what is so hard to understand,all I need is DELTA ROWS between two queries..PLAIN SIMPLE

Comment: Shoutimg is not going to get you anywhere. As both Jason and myself repeatedly told you: you need to tell us how to determine what's a delta, what is not a delta. You only provided one sample difference, but failed to provide a detailed description of the above.

Comment: `how to determine what's a delta`-- notice the last few digits BTFM.HW_NPR.1.1-00007,it is BTFM.HW_NPR.1.1-00006 ,the whole row comes as delta,so unless all the column data matches the row comes up as delta

Answer (score 0):

**LEFT JOIN METHOD** - SLOW

Ive never used the not exists method before but maybe if you left join the second query to your first query and get results where it only appears in the first query should work. I think something like this:

```
SELECT 
    query_1.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        si.software_image_id,
            si.software_image,
            sib.software_image_build,
            si.software_image_tag_id
    FROM
        software_product_builds spb
    INNER JOIN software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
    INNER JOIN software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
    INNER JOIN software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id
    WHERE
        spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-7') AS query_1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        si.software_image_id,
            si.software_image,
            sib.software_image_build,
            si.software_image_tag_id
    FROM
        software_product_builds spb
    INNER JOIN software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
    INNER JOIN software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
    INNER JOIN software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id
    WHERE
        spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-6') AS query_2 ON query_1.software_image_build = query_2.software_image_build
WHERE
    query_2.software_image_build IS NULL
```

Assuming that the software_product_build is the unique field you want to test against

**NOT IN METHOD** - SLOW

IF left join is bad for performance you can do a simple where field is not in the second query like:

```
SELECT 
    si.software_image_id,
    si.software_image,
    sib.software_image_build,
    si.software_image_tag_id
FROM
    software_product_builds spb
        INNER JOIN
    software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
        INNER JOIN
    software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
        INNER JOIN
    software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id
WHERE
    spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-7'
        AND sib.software_image_build NOT IN (SELECT 
            sib.software_image_build
        FROM
            software_product_builds spb
                INNER JOIN
            software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
                INNER JOIN
            software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
                INNER JOIN
            software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id
        WHERE
            spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-6')
```

Either way you still need to determine what your unique identifier is so you can check that it doesn't exist in the second query (like @shadow has pointed out). How does SQL know what match to check doesnt exist? SQL needs to know exactly what it is matching. Even if you need to check a combination of fields by concatenating them like:

```
WHERE CONCAT(si.software_image, sib.software_image_build,) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(si.software_image,sib.software_image_build) FROM .......,
```

**FINAL UPDATE, NOT EXISTS METHOD** - BEST FOR PERFORMANCE

On the back of shadows comments i have found `NOT EXISTS` method to be far better on performance. So try:

```
SELECT 
    si.software_image_id,
    si.software_image,
    sib.software_image_build,
    si.software_image_tag_id
FROM
    software_product_builds spb
        INNER JOIN
    software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib ON spb.software_product_build_id = spbsib.software_product_build_id
        INNER JOIN
    software_image_builds sib ON spbsib.software_image_build_id = sib.software_image_build_id
        INNER JOIN
    software_images si ON sib.software_image_id = si.software_image_id
WHERE
    spb.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-7'
        AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            software_product_builds spb_two
                INNER JOIN
            software_product_build_software_image_builds spbsib_two ON spb_two.software_product_build_id = spbsib_two.software_product_build_id
                INNER JOIN
            software_image_builds sib_two ON spbsib_two.software_image_build_id = sib_two.software_image_build_id
                INNER JOIN
            software_images si_two ON sib_two.software_image_id = si_two.software_image_id
        WHERE
            spb_two.software_product_build = 'CI_xxxx.LA.0.1-03291-STD.INT-6'
                AND sib_two.software_image_id = sib.software_image_id)
```

Comment: How to relate the 2 queries is the thing I do not understand either. Btw, the performance of a not exists subquery is usually better for this type of question than a left join, since not exists does not have to pull any data from the expression on the right hand side, whereas the join would do.

Comment: they are not related,they are two seperate queries ..question is how to print only the rows from query#1 not present in query#2,if not exists doesn't work ,is there any alternative?

Comment: @user3508811 if the 2 queries were not related to each othet, then your question would not make any sense at all. You have to define when you consider a record in the outer query being present in the subquery. That will be your relationship.

Comment: @JasonJoslin I did not say that ledt join has bad performance, just that not exists usually has better performance for this particular type of question. Not in also needs to fetch the underlying records to do the matching, so its performance also usually not aa good as not exists in this particular type of question

Comment: Cool thanks @shadow. Yeah I think `NOT IN` is actually worse than using a left join because then (im pretty sure) it needs to run the subquery condition for every result found on the left side. I'm probably going to delete my answer FYI

Comment: No need to delete the answer, it describes 2 alternative ways to get to the same result as the not exists query. You just miss the vital information from the OP to complete it.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow for the suggestion of using a `NOT EXISTS` for better performance. I used it today at work for one of my queries. WOW so much faster, Wish i knew about this beauty ages ago.